# self parameter error celery

Tags: python, celery

I saw some blogs online where they put self parameters on their celery functions, why is mine causing an error like:

```
TypeError: xml_gr() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Here is my code:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=5))
def xml_gr(self):
    ftp = FTP('xxxxx')
    ftp.login(user='xxxxx', passwd='xxxxx')
    x = xml_operation('AGIN', GR_GLOBAL_CURRENT_DATE, ftp, "GR")
    ftp.close()
```

Comment: Self parameter is used in Class-based Celery Tasks. Once check this http://jsatt.com/blog/class-based-celery-tasks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"self" is used within class member functions.  When you call a member function in an instance of the class, the language automatically passes in the class instance as "self".  "self" lets you access the members of the class.

```
class Thing:
    var1 = None
    def set_member(self, value):
        self.var1 = value

    def show_member(self, value):
        return self.var1
```

---

Then usage would be

```
a = Thing()
a.set_member(23)
a.show_member()
```

And you'd see the response `23`.  You don't have to pass in the "self" variable explicitly.

When you declare functions outside of a class, there is no reason to use "self".

Comment: I'm actually looking for an answer related  to celery not the actual python itself

Comment: Its the same situation with celery as well.  If you're not declaring the function within a class, you don't use "self".  self is a language construct that passes the class instance into a function so you can access the members.  Since you aren't doing that, you shouldn't tell the function to expect "self".  That's why it says `takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the accepted answer, `self` is used in celery to bind tasks.

```
Bound tasks are needed for retries. for accessing information about 
the current task request, and for any additional functionality 
you add to custom task base classes.
```

So, if you specify `@task(bind=True)` then you need add `self` as the first argument. Otherwise, not needed.

[Source](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html)